# If his son is dead: "His son was John Smith", "His son is John Smith"

Tags: existential-constructions

If someone's son has died, would you say: "His son was John Smith" or "His son is John Smith"? Dying stops you from being, but would that stop someone from being someone's son?

Comment: If you follow [Shakespear](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/56968/speech-friends-romans-countrymen-lend-me-your-ears), you cease to be many things when you die: Caesar _was_ my friend, he _was_ ambitious. My guess is he _was_ somebody's son.

Comment: If I was commenting, *I* would say: (i) His dead son was John (Smith). (ii) His son, John Smith, is dead now. (iii) He used to have a son, who recently passed away. (iv) John was Tom Smith's son. (v) Tom Smith's dead son, John, was a journalist. But if I am the father and I am pointing at his image in a photo, I'd probably say: *"That's my son, John"* because to me he will always be my son.

Comment: @oerkelens: and Shakespeare greatest work was or is  Macbeth?

Comment: @QuoraFeans The work still exists, so it _is_. If the father dies, the son _is_ still the son.